# ViM provides a list of alternative snippets, but I'm not able to select any of them

Tags: vim, ultisnips, vim-snipmate

I can navigate up and down in the list, but if I press Enter when one of them is selected, it just inserts that value, e.g. `html5` and exists from the dropdown. 
How can I select one and have the snippet triggered?

This is my snippet config:

```
  Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
  Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
```

I'm also using `Valloric/YouCompleteMe`. No special config for that plugin, though.

[image]

Comment: I have the exact [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685512/how-to-expand-an-ultisnips-snippet-using-c-y-in-the-youcompleteme-pop-up-menu). Did you find any solution for that since then?

Comment: I wrote a solution to this problem, you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685512/how-to-expand-an-ultisnips-snippet-using-c-y-in-the-youcompleteme-pop-up-menu/59865970#59865970).

Answer (score 1):

Try `:help ultisnips`

```
g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger               <tab>
g:UltiSnipsListSnippets                <c-tab>
g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger          <c-j>
g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger         <c-k>
```

In my case I have:

```
" snippets
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<C-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<C-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<C-k>"
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
let g:UltiSnipsListSnippets="<C-Space>"
```